# Conditional Sum Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to aggregate and sum values from a Pandas Dataframe based on the values in the column "Gender". This is a sample of the dataset that I am working on:

```
df_genders = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['US','US','US','US','US','India','India','India','UK','UK','UK','UK'],
                          'Gender': ['Man','Woman', 'Non-Binary,Genderqueer', 'Non-Binary', 'Non-Binary,Genderqueer,Non-Conforming',
                                    'Man','Woman','Non-Binary','Man','Woman', 'Non-Binary,Genderqueer', 'Non-Binary,Genderqueer,Non-Conforming'],
                          'Count': [7996,915,11,34,153,3857,287,47,2566,272,72,99]})
df_genders
```

Since the values of Gender are not very consistent, I would like to group them together and sum their Counts in order to obtain for each country the sum of Men, Women and Non-Binary (Non-Binary being nor "Man" nor "Woman").
I wasn't able to write a code for conditional grouping and summing, therefore my approach was to find out the totals per Country and then subtract from the totals the sum of man + woman, being thus left with the sum of non-binary:

```
df_genders.groupby('Country')['Count'].sum() - df_genders[(df_genders['Gender']=='Man') | (df_genders['Gender']=='Woman')].groupby('Country')['Count'].sum()
```

Do you know a better way to solve this or in general a way for performing conditional aggregations (group by and sum)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do directly:

```
res = df_genders[~df_genders['Gender'].isin(('Man', 'Woman'))]['Count'].sum()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
416
```

But I think is better if you create a new column with the classification you are seeking, for example, one approach:

```
df_genders['grouped-genders'] = df_genders['Gender'].map({ 'Man' : 'Man', 'Woman' : 'Woman' }).fillna('Non-Binary')
print(df_genders)
```

**Output**

```
   Country                                 Gender  Count grouped-genders
0       US                                    Man   7996             Man
1       US                                  Woman    915           Woman
2       US                 Non-Binary,Genderqueer     11      Non-Binary
3       US                             Non-Binary     34      Non-Binary
4       US  Non-Binary,Genderqueer,Non-Conforming    153      Non-Binary
5    India                                    Man   3857             Man
6    India                                  Woman    287           Woman
7    India                             Non-Binary     47      Non-Binary
8       UK                                    Man   2566             Man
9       UK                                  Woman    272           Woman
10      UK                 Non-Binary,Genderqueer     72      Non-Binary
11      UK  Non-Binary,Genderqueer,Non-Conforming     99      Non-Binary
```

and then group by the new column to obtain the count of all the genders:

```
res = df_genders.groupby('grouped-genders')['Count'].sum().reset_index()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  grouped-genders  Count
0             Man  14419
1      Non-Binary    416
2           Woman   1474
```

Comment: Thank you Dani! I added to the groupby also the column "Country" and the result is exactly what I wanted :)